# Как правильно написать "объект котельная"?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Как правильно написать предложение:

**Прошу Вас прислать представителя на объект котельная, расположенный по адресу: ...**

Нужно ли как-то выделить наименование объекта "котельная"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот результат моих поисков в Сети.

Наиболее авторитетный из найденных документов - РАСПОРЯЖЕНИЕ МИНИСТЕРСТВА ПО УПРАВЛЕНИЮ ГОСУДАРСТВЕННЫМ ИМУЩЕСТВОМ РЕСПУБЛИКИ ДАГЕСТАН О ПРАВЕ СОБСТВЕННОСТИ МУНИЦИПАЛЬНОГО ОБРАЗОВАНИЯ "ТАБАСАРАНСКИЙ РАЙОН" НА **ОБЪЕКТ "ШКОЛА НА 320 УЧЕНИЧЕСКИХ МЕСТ В С. ЧУЛАТ ТАБАСАРАНСКОГО РАЙОНА"**

:В судебных решениях о праве собственности встречаются разные варианты:

- объект "Здание управления";
- объект недвижимости - ангар;
- право собственности ответчика на объект: здание склада;
- право собственности Кузнецова С.В. на объект здание бойлерная.

По-моему, если в организации (строительной, например) есть список объектов, в котором у каждого объекта есть название, и в этом списке фигурирует объект под названием "Котельная", то так его и надо упоминать. А если в вашем обращении слово "объект" употреблено просто ради соблюдения стиля, то см. ответ @shampar.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Уточню, письмо с этим предложением - официальное, слово "объект" обязательно должно присутствовать.

Answer (score 1):

Жилые дома, детские площадки, стоянки, другие элементы городской среды — её объекты. Из этого следует, что добавлять к наименованию объекта слово *объект* излишне и их надо **развести** по крайней мере, но оно, наименование, должно быть информативно полным, т. е. с указанием его номера и ответственной организации.

Вар. 1. Прошу прислать представителя на объект (котельная №5 ЖЭКа, ОДС, ДЕЗа и РЭУ по адресу: ...) к 15:00.

Вар. 2. Прошу прислать представителя на объект — котельная №5 ЖЭКа, ОДС, ДЕЗа и РЭУ по адресу: ... — к 15:00.

Вар. 3. Прошу прислать представителя к котельной №5 ЖЭКа, ОДС, ДЕЗа и РЭУ по адресу: ... — к 15:00.

Comment: Спасибо большое!